# cakephp 3 and view cells with use of Cookie

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I can't find any info about using $this->Cookie in view cells.
When i wrote code like this, error will arise:

namespace App\View\Cell;

```
use Cake\View\Cell;

class CityCell extends Cell {

  public function display() {
      $this->Cookie->config('encryption', false);
      $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('city');
  }
}
```

and the error is:
Error: Call to a member function read() on null

So can we use cookie in view cells ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That of course won't work, view cells do not support the use of components, altough they can be thought of like "mini-controllers", they are not actually controllers in the terms of CakePHPs MVC system.

Depending on whether the cookies are encrypted, you can either use the request object to fetch them in your cell

```
$this->request->cookie('cookieName')
```

or

```
$this->request->cookies
```

see also **[API > \Cake\Network\Request::cookie()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Network.Http.Request.html#_cookie)**

or, in case they *are* encrypted, you have grab them via the Cookie component, and then for example pass them down from your controller to the view, and finally into the cell like

**controller**

```
public function controllerAction() {
    // ...
    $this->set('cookie', $this->Cookie->read('cookieName'));
}
```

**cell**

```
public function display($cookie) {
    // ...
}
```

**view**

```
$this->cell('CellName', ['cookie' => $cookie]);
```

see also **[Cookbook > Views > View Cells > Passing Arguments to a Cell](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html#passing-arguments-to-a-cell)**

Comment: $this->request->cookie('cookieName') works well.
Thanks.